# iOS: Code Signing with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, code-signing, ipa

Just switched my app to `use_frameworks` with `Cocoapods`, everything builds fine and works fine on the phone and in our CI server. But when uploading the `ipa` to iTunes Connect, I get an error of

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '[CORRECT_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER]' for key 'application-identifier' in '[PATH_TO_PODS_FRAMEWORK]' is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier.

This error comes up for EACH framework used in the app (I have 10 pods in the app, and I have 10 errors on the screen) not sure what I should do. any ideas?

Comment: Search `application-identifier` in your whole project and check it is correct identifier. i think your pod file contain duplicate or incorrect identifier.

Comment: none of the pod frameworks even have that key in their plist file

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Are you archiving via `xcodebuild -exportArchive`?